# Increment variables in files

Tags: perl

I am a complete rookie with Perl. What I am trying to do is to open a list of files, increment three different variables in each file, save the files, and close.

The variables look like this

```
This_Is_My_Variable03
This_Is_My_Variable02
This_Is_My_Variable01
```

The variable ending in 01 is in the file multiple times.  The variables are at times part of a Character string.  the `This_Is_My_Variable` part of the variable never changes.

Thanks.

This may not be the best solution but it works

```
#!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Tie::File;

tie my @data, 'Tie::File', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;

s/(This_Is_My_Variable)(\d+)+/$1.++($_=$2)/eg for @data;

untie @data;
```

Thank you Borodin for getting me started with `Tie::File`: that definitely helped.

Second solution using while loop

```
#!perl=C:\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin\perl
use warnings;

#use strict;

sub inc {
    my ($num) = @_;
    ++$num;
}

open(FILE, "myfile.txt") || die $!;
$i = 0;
while (<FILE>) {
    $string = $_;
    if (/This_Is_My_Variable../) {
        $string =~ s/(This_Is_My_Variable)(\d+)+/$1.++($_=$2)/eg;
        print "$string \n";
        $i++;
    }
    else {
        print "$string \n";
    }
}

close FILE;
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far? Reading these documents [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html), [close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) and [Auto-increment and Auto-decrement](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) should get you started.

Comment: StackOverflow is really not the right place to learning Perl from scratch. Why don't you spend a little time learning the basics, try [the Modern Perl Book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) and come back if you still have questions.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.

Comment: If I actaully knew any about Perl I would have. But it seems if you know nothing about Perl you cannot get an answer. If you know something then People will help. After speding several days of digging around I got this to work. perl -i.bak -lpe "BEGIN { sub inc { my ($num) = @_; ++$num } } s/(This_Is_My_Variable)(\d+)/$1 . (inc($2))/eg" File.txt Thank you kindly for your help it is really appreciated. I need to get it to work without the .bak file so I figure another week or so and I should have it. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your *"Second solution using while loop"* has a number of problems.

- *Never* disable `use strict` to get a program working. All that does is hide problems in your code
- You have an unused subroutine `inc` and an unused variable `$i`
- You should always use the three-parameter form of `open`, and lexical file handles
- There is no need to test whether the line contains a string before applying a substitution
- You can simply use `($2+1)` in your replacement string, rather than assigning the value to `$_` and incrementing it with `++($_=$2)`
- If you are going to use a named variable for the lines read from the file, then generally you should use `while (my $string = <$fh>) {...}`. For short blocks like this it is better just to use `$_`
- You don't `chomp` the input, which would be fine except you are printing an additional space and newline after each line
- You have `print "$string \n"` in your code twice. It may as well appear just once outside the `if` structure

This code performs the same process. I hope it helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', 'myfile.txt') || die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    s/(This_Is_My_Variable)(\d+)/$1.($2+1)/eg;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Borodin thank you for the explanations.  This does help.  I have marked this as the correct answer since it works and I like your substition sting better than the one I posted.  Yours is more straight forward.  The one question I have is, why do you not have to close the file?  I tried close $fh; and got an error.  Thank your very much for the help.  You are the second person to advise to use the three parameter form of open so I will start going with that.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

tie my @data, 'Tie::File', 'myfile' or die $!;

s/(\d+)$/sprintf '%02d', $1+1/e for @data;
```

Comment: I do not completely understand what is going on with this.  I used this and it works.  I do not understand how since I do not declare what I am incrementing.  It does not work in what I am incrementing is within a line or further down in the body.  More later.      #!perl=C:\bin\perl
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    
    use Tie::File;
    
    tie my @data, 'Tie::File', 'myfile.txt' or die $!;
    
    s/(\d+)$/sprintf '%02d', $1+1/e for @data;